# Birt Weblogic Deployment Failed Error

Tags: weblogic, birt

I try to deploy birt's WebViewerExample in Weblogic by this [tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BirtPOJO_Viewer_WebLogic_Deployment).But I got this error in weblogic console.

`

```
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:28 AM SGT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener   org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener failed: java.lang.LinkageErro
r: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.getSchemaTypeInfo()Lorg/w3c/dom/TypeInfo;" the clas
s loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloade
r>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Element have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo used in the signature.
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.getSchemaTypeInfo()Lorg/w3c/do
m/TypeInfo;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl, and the class loader (i
nstance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Element have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo used in the signature
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.loadExtensions(BundleLoader.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.load(BundleLoader.java:63)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:29 AM SGT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1393208840384' for task '1'. Error is: 'weblog
ic.application.ModuleException: '
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.getSchemaTypeInfo()
Lorg/w3c/dom/TypeInfo;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl, and the clas
s loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Element have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo used in the signature
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.loadExtensions(BundleLoader.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.load(BundleLoader.java:63)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:29 AM SGT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application 'birt'.>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:29 AM SGT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'birt'.>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:29 AM SGT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.getSchemaTypeInfo()
Lorg/w3c/dom/TypeInfo;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl, and the clas
s loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Element have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo used in the signature
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.loadExtensions(BundleLoader.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.load(BundleLoader.java:63)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:30 AM SGT> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl.getSchemaTypeInfo()
Lorg/w3c/dom/TypeInfo;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/ElementImpl, and the clas
s loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Element have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo used in the signature
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.synchronizeChildren(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.getDocumentElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.loadExtensions(BundleLoader.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.BundleLoader.load(BundleLoader.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.installBundle(ServicePlatform.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServiceLauncher.startup(ServiceLauncher.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.startup(Platform.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.setEngineContext(ReportEngineService.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.setContext(BirtViewerReportService.java:1022)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ViewerServletContextListener.java:62)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:27:30 AM SGT> <Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=
WebAppApplicationOverviewPage&WebAppApplicationOverviewPortlethandle=com.bea.console.handles.AppDeploymentHandle%28%22com.bea%3AName%3Dbirt%2CType%3DAppDeployment%22%29.>
<Feb 24, 2014 10:29:15 AM SGT> <Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=
WebAppApplicationOverviewPage&WebAppApplicationOverviewPortlethandle=com.bea.console.handles.AppDeploymentHandle%28%22com.bea%3AName%3Dbirt%2CType%3DAppDeployment%22%29.>
```

`

In weblogic the deployed war is not in Active state.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The solution which worked for me is I deleted the org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar file  inside birt-runtime-4_3_1\WebViewerExample\WEB-INF\lib ..It works like a  charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me is I deleted the org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v201101211617.jar file inside birt-runtime-4_3_1\WebViewerExample\WEB-INF\lib ..It works like a charm